# SQL Azure data replication between two Azure subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, azure

Since I initially created an Azure SQL Server database while building an app for a client, they have changed Azure subscriptions. The client wants the database migrated to a new account and eventually deprecate use on the old account when we are done with the new version of the app. In the meantime, they want any updates from the old database duplicated into the new database.

My question is, is there a way to update two databases, one a copy of the other, at the same time on separate Azure accounts?

I've read into `active geo-replication` but that looks like it can only be done between two databases in the same Azure subscription.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Active geo-replication` indeed is only possible inside a subscription, if you are using Azure SQL that wouldn't be possible with it. You could possibly use some kind of replication using on Premise SQL, but that would be pretty hacky. You would want to work with Azure SQL Data Sync.

If you are using a VM with the SQL Server you could create AlwaysOn databases for that purpose.

But if the question is: `My question is, is there a way to update two databases, one a copy of the other, at the same time on separate Azure accounts?`. You could probably code your application in such a way to write to 2 databases, but again, you would also need to keep track of operations